# Одинаковый текст при проверке оказался разным

Tags: sql, excel

Из двух баз данных SQL взяты два одинаковых значения. Обратите внимание на формулу наверху. Пробелов нигде нет. Как это вообще возможно? Может быть разные кодировки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могут быть разные коды внешне похожих символов. Пример: *с* (99, 241), *о* (111, 238)

Возможно наличие служебных символов. Пример: символы 10, 32, 160 - если в ячейке не установлен перенос строки, все эти символы видны как пробел (реальный пробел - символ 32)

Проверить просто. Вписать формулу в ячейку и копировать вниз:

```
=КОДСИМВ(ПСТР($A$1;СТРОКА(A1);1))=КОДСИМВ(ПСТР($A$2;СТРОКА(A1);1))
```